# HTTP 418 transport errors from Evernote API

Tags: evernote

For the last 12 hours we have been getting a lot of Transport errors with "HTTP Response code: 418". That made sync of users data practically impossible.

Has anything changed in how clients should communicate to the API or is it temporary error related to Wednesday's release?

Comment: Did you try to use a teapot by mistake? :p   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved the problem by changing URL for UserStore from https://www.evernote.com/edam/user to https://www.evernote.com//edam/user (used by official SDKs)

Comment: Do you know how to login?